C++20: Concepts and CRTP
I have trying to use concepts and CRTP pattern in my project but I see compilation errors using both gcc-12 and MSVC 2022.  Here is the simplified code:
namespace Test
{
    namespace concepts {
        template<typename T>
        concept SupportsFn = requires(T t, int k) {
            {
                t.fn(k)
            };
        };
    }

    template<concepts::SupportsFn D>
    class CD {
        static_assert(concepts::SupportsFn<D>);
    public:
        void call(int k) {
            this->fn(k);
        }
    };

    template<concepts::SupportsFn T>
    class BD : public CD<T> {
        static_assert(concepts::SupportsFn<T>);
    public:
        void call2(int k) {
            this->fn(k + 2);
        }
    };
}

class ED : public Test::BD<ED> {
public:
    void fn(int k) {
        std::cout << "FN " << k << " \n";
    }
};

int main() {


    ED ed{};
    ed.call(10);

    return 0;
}

Both GCC and MSVC have compilation error that template constraints are not satisfied because of incomplete type ED.  Here is an example of the MSVC error:
>  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\expected(11): warning STL4038: The contents of <expected> are available only with C++23 or later.
1>  C:\temp\memfnexpt\memfnexpt\memfnexpt.cpp(377,25): error C7602: 'Test::BD': the associated constraints are not satisfied
1>      C:\temp\memfnexpt\memfnexpt\memfnexpt.cpp(368,2):
1>      see declaration of 'Test::BD'
1>      C:\temp\memfnexpt\memfnexpt\memfnexpt.cpp(367,11):
1>      the concept 'Test::concepts::SupportsFn<ED>' evaluated to false
1>          C:\temp\memfnexpt\memfnexpt\memfnexpt.cpp(353,5):
1>          use of undefined type 'ED'
1>          C:\temp\memfnexpt\memfnexpt\memfnexpt.cpp(377,7):
1>          see declaration of 'ED'
1>          C:\temp\memfnexpt\memfnexpt\memfnexpt.cpp(353,7):

How do I use concepts with CRTP and get around this error?

It has nothing to do with CRTP. The check would fail without it in the same way: https://godbolt.org/z/3YqfvM11n

But you make it worse than in my link above: You want the base class to be valid only if the derived class has a certain member, which depends on the contents of both the derived class and its base circularly. How is the decision supposed to be made? You can't have the circular reasoning. Why do the base classes need the constraints?

Also, as a side note: this->fn(k) is wrong. You probably meant static_cast<T*>(this)->fn(k); instead. And also, the static_asserts are of course redundant with the constraints in the template heads. They can never fail.

What you can do is put the constraints on the member functions instead of the base class itself. Those are checked only when the functions are actually called.

Having concepts on a CRTP-like construction is a good point, for instance when one wants to (statically) implement a Template Method design pattern. According to the point of @user17732522, something like this could be done. Although one would prefer to put the concept on the class itself (which is not possible), having the concept itself on the method is not bad after all and could serve as some method documentation since the way to use the method is just at the same location as the method declaration itself.

Thank you edrezen and user17732522.  I wanted to use concepts in CRTP for template method pattern without virtual functions.  However I realized that I was using concepts before the definition.  I will switch to using static_assert in the method to fulfill the method.
